# How to convert a string to a structured tabular table?

Tags: python

I got a string like this:

```
'[{"id":"SP500","date":"2009-05-12","close":"908.3500"},
  {"id":"SP500","date":"2009-05-13","close":"883.9200"},
  {"id":"SP500","date":"2009-05-14","close":"893.0700"},
  {"id":"SP500","date":"2009-05-15","close":"882.8800"},
  {"id":"SP500","date":"2009-05-18","close":"909.7100"}]'
```

and i need to convert it to a table. I got no idea.

I'm trying to use split or find function, but far from anwser.

Please help!!

Comment: Do you mean a `pandas` dataframe?

Comment: yes, I want a functions or methods to transfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is a valid JSON fragment. Assuming `s` is your string and by "structured tabular table" you mean a Pandas DataDrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(s)
#    close       date     id
#0  908.35 2009-05-12  SP500
#1  883.92 2009-05-13  SP500
#2  893.07 2009-05-14  SP500
#3  882.88 2009-05-15  SP500
#4  909.71 2009-05-18  SP500
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!! I figured it out!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to the standard library you can use the json and csv modules.

```
import json
import csv

data = json.loads('''[{"id":"SP500","date":"2009-05-12","close":"908.3500"},
  {"id":"SP500","date":"2009-05-13","close":"883.9200"},
  {"id":"SP500","date":"2009-05-14","close":"893.0700"},
  {"id":"SP500","date":"2009-05-15","close":"882.8800"},
  {"id":"SP500","date":"2009-05-18","close":"909.7100"}]''')

with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as fp:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fp, ('id', 'date', 'close'))
    for line in data:
        writer.writerow(line)
```